# Different output at each compilation

Tags: javascript, amazon-cloudwatch

When i compile, the output of my parameter "derniere" is different..

I have the impression that he runs my JSON randomly

I am using the JSON for my loop for

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var arr = [{
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "Value": "https://***",
    "cle": "1"
}, {
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "Value": "https://***",
    "cle": "2"
}, {
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "Value": "https://***",
    "cle": "3"
},]
//************* END JSON ********************

for(key in arr){
    console.log(arr[key]);
    var region = arr[key].region;
    var Value_t = arr[key].Value;


    // ********** CONFIGURATION**************
    AWS.config.region = region;
    var cw = new AWS.CloudWatch({apiVersion: '2010-08-01'});
    var startDate = new Date();
    var endDate = new Date();
    startDate.setHours(startDate.getHours()-1);

    var params2 = {   
        StartTime: startDate,
        EndTime: endDate,
        Namespace: 'Lambda-Ping/HTTP', /* required */
        Period: 300, /* required */
        MetricName: 'Latency', /* required */
        Dimensions: [{   
            Name: 'Endpoint', /* required */
            Value: Value_t
        },
        /* more items */
        ],
        Statistics: [
            'Average'
            /* more items */
        ],
    };
// ************ END CONFIGURATION ************
    cw.getMetricStatistics(params2, function(err, data) {
      if (err){
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      }
      else{    
        for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
          var tableau = data.Datapoints[i].Average;
        }
        derniere.push(parseInt(tableau));
        console.log("Derniere: "+derniere+"\n");
        // OUTPUT different Derniere: 400, 1000, 200
        // OUTPUT different Derniere: 1000, 200, 400
        // OUTPUT need Derniere: 200, 1000, 400
      }
   });
}
```

Sometimes I have :

- Derniere: 200,400,1000
- Derniere: 400,200,1000
- Derniere: 1000,400,200

But the result that I want is:

- Derniere : 200,1000,400

...and this, for each compilation.

Comment: I tried to fix the indentation of your code, but it is ambihuous: there are unclosed braces: the `for` loop does  not have a closing brace, nor the callback function near the end. It is also not clear what the scope of the `else` is? Please provide syntactically correct code.

Comment: Yes i'm sorry for these errors. I just corrected
I would just like the result to be executed in JSON order. Thanks for you help

Comment: It is still not OK: with indentation you seem to think the `else` near the end includes more than just the `for` loop. This is not the case. Please fix the indentation or add braces in the `else` block.

Comment: I just added braces in the else block

Comment: I look at what you did and can only think "OK, indentation is not your strong point". Let me fix that for you....

Comment: I'm really sorry, next time I'll pay more attention to the indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the unpredictable order is that `getMetricStatistics` performs a HTTP request, which is asynchronous. Some of these calls may return a response faster than others, possibly leading to a different order than the order in which you call `getMetricStatistics`.

Here is how you can solve it. First make sure to *declare* `key` instead of making it an implicit global (which is bad practice). In this case it  *should* be a block scope variable, so use `const` or `let`, not `var`:

```
for (const key in arr){
//   ^^^^^
```

Then in the callback of `getMetricStatistics` don't use `push`, but use `key` to store the response:

```
derniere[key] = parseInt(tableau);
```

Now the responses still come in an unpredictable order, but you store them in a predictable location. At the end, the array `derniere` will be complete.

Comment: It works, Thanks you so much. I'm extremly sorry for the indentation.